# Animated images for iMessage extensions?

Tags: animation, imessage

I have no problem sending images but when I try to attach an APNG or a GIF file to the MSMessageTemplateLayout using either image and mediaFileURL, none of the images are animated...

How are people able to send stickers with an iMessage APP?

```
NSURLComponents* components = [[NSURLComponents alloc] init];
components.queryItems = [setup iMessageData]; //returns query items array

MSMessageTemplateLayout* layout = [[MSMessageTemplateLayout alloc] init];
//loaded via assets
//layout.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testSticker"];

//loaded via bundle
layout.mediaFileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"testSticker" withExtension:@"png"];    
layout.caption = @"Test String"

MSMessage* message = [[MSMessage alloc] init];
message.URL = components.URL;
message.layout = layout;

[self.activeConversation insertMessage:message completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CollectionView` or a `MSStickerBrowserViewController` to create a collection of sticker.

If you want to use `CollectionView`, inside each cell you need to create a `MSStickerView`, so create a `MSSticker`: 
`let sticker = try MSSticker(contentsOfFileURL: URL_OF_FILE, localizedDescription: "PNG")`

If you want to use `MSStickerBrowserViewController`, create the `MSSticker` as well and populate inside `stickerBrowserView(_:stickerAt:)` ( more details in: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messages/msstickerbrowserviewdatasource )